# How to keep the shell window open after running a PowerShell script?

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have a very short PowerShell script that connects to a server and imports the AD module. I'd like to run the script simply by double clicking, but I'm afraid the window immediately closes after the last line.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Related (duplicate): *[How to get PowerShell to keep a command window open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244280)*

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You basically have 3 options to prevent the PowerShell Console window from closing, that I describe [in more detail on my blog post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/keep-powershell-console-window-open-after-script-finishes-running/).

1. **One-time Fix:** Run your script from the PowerShell Console, or launch the PowerShell process using the -NoExit switch. e.g. `PowerShell -NoExit "C:\SomeFolder\SomeScript.ps1"`
2. **Per-script Fix:** Add a prompt for input to the end of your script file. e.g. `Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"`
3. **Global Fix:** Change your registry key by adding the `-NoExit` switch to always leave the PowerShell Console window open after the script finishes running.

```
Registry Key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\powershell.exe\shell\open\command
Description: Key used when you right-click a .ps1 file and choose Open With -> Windows PowerShell.
Default Value: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "%1"
Desired Value: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "& \"%1\""

Registry Key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command
Description: Key used when you right-click a .ps1 file and choose Run with PowerShell (shows up depending on which Windows OS and Updates you have installed).
Default Value: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
Desired Value: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoExit "-Command" "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & \"%1\""
```

See my blog for more information and a script to download that will make the registry change for you.

Comment: OPs answer also works as per-script fix: wrap your script with a `powershell -NoExit -Command { <The script to actually run> }`
Enables user to start the script via UI and see the results without editing registry keys

Comment: How can I make a shortcut that opens a PowerShell window (not cmd) with `-NoExit` and runs SomeScript.ps1?

Comment: It looks like `start` is what I needed. Created a batch file with `start PowerShell -NoExit -File "[.ps1 script path]"`. Without `start` it was running PowerShell within the Windows Command prompt.

Comment: #3  doesn't work on Win 10 Pro v 10.0.19044 Build 19044

Comment: You could also associate the PowerShell ISE application with your script.

Answer (score 31):

Errr...
I should have known:

```
powershell -noexit <path\script>
```

and that's all there's to it :)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The problem might be that you are appending -NoExit after the script path, it needs to go before. I think if it is after it passes it as an argument to the script instead of powershell.exe.

Answer (score 6):

The solution below prevents the script from closing when running Powershell ISE and allows the script to close otherwise.

```
# If running in the console, wait for input before closing.
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")
{
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add pause on a new line at the bottom of the script, as in a batch file.

Comment: This does not work for me. When running the script with the 'Pause' line at the end, PowerShell launches and I'm presented with "Press Enter to continue...:"
When I press Enter, the script runs and then closes on completion as it would  without the 'Pause' function.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `pause` at the end of your script if you just want the window to stay open, or you can add `powershell` if you want to be able to run commands afterwards (obviously don't do the second option if anyone else will use your code).

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, I wanted to add powershell to context menu on windows 7. That is right clicking on a folder or inside a folder to get a menu to launch Powershell window without it closing after launch. The answers here helped me do just that and I want to share it here incase it helps someone else.

- Launch registry editor by pressing WIN + R
  type regedit.exe and hit enter
- Navigate to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell**
- Right click on shell and create a key give it a name e.g PowershellHere
- On the right pane, double click on Default and provide a descriptive name e.g Powershell Here
- Right click on the PowershellHere key you created earlier and create a new key and name it "command" please make sure you name it exactly so but without the quotes.
- On the right pane, double click on Default and then type the command below
- **C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -noexit -Command CD '"%1"'**
  *-noexit flag makes sure that the Powershell windows does not close again immediately after launch*
  *'"%1"' flag represents the folder you right clicked*
  *-Command CD '"%1"' will ensure the Powershell changes into the right clicked directory.*

To make the right click work inside a folder meaning right clicking an empty space inside a folder, repeat the steps but this time, the registry location is:

**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell** 
*And the command is:* 
**C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -noexit**

> *Tested on windows 7 ultimate sp1 but I think I might work for later versions of Windows as well*

Answer (score 0):

While the original poster asked for PowerShell 2.0, all current answers should work up to PowerShell <6 (`powershell.exe`). For modern PowerShell >= 6 (`pwsh.exe`) you can merge the following registry directives as a global configuration to have the PowerShell host keeping its window open after running the script:

```
; Set to run .ps1 scripts with double click and pwsh and to not exit after running script
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe -noexit -Command \"$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'PowerShell 7 (x64)'; & '%1'\""

; Set to run .ps1 scripts in the context menu with pwsh and to not exit after running script
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\PowerShell7x64\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe -noexit -Command \"$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'PowerShell 7 (x64)'; & '%1'\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\runas\Command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe -noexit -Command \"$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'PowerShell 7 (x64)'; & '%1'\""
```

It works with Windows 10 and PowerShell 7. Feel free to suggest fixes for Windows 11, as it appears there's now a global [location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623597/213871) for the PowerShell command.