# Call PowerShell script from VBScript but windows close

Tags: powershell, vbscript

This VBScript runs a few PowerShell scripts. I put the invocation of `notepad.exe` there to make sure it ran as an admin.

My PowerShell scripts open consoles but then they close immediately.
I would like to have them stay open.

What is wrong?

Here is my VBScript:

```
RunAsAdmin()

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -file .\Source\RemoveWindows10Apps-2.0.ps1"), 1 , True

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -file .\Source\ChangeWin10StartLayout.ps1"), 1 , True

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -file .\Source\NewFolder.ps1"), 1 , True

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shell.Run("notepad.exe"), 1 , True


Function RunAsAdmin()
  Dim objAPP
  If WScript.Arguments.length = 0 Then
    Set objAPP = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objAPP.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & _
    WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & " RunAsAdministrator",,"runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the shell window open after running a PowerShell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739322/how-to-keep-the-shell-window-open-after-running-a-powershell-script)

Comment: It has something to do with the RunAsAdmin function because when I take it out my windows stay open but they don't run as an admin.

Comment: Does the answer have to be in VBScript?  Here is some powershell that [elevates within the script](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2010/09/23/a-self-elevating-powershell-script/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because you use relative paths so when your script will call itself as admin your current directory will change to `...\WINDOWS\system32`.

Try it with building absolute paths and pass them to PowerShell like so

```
RunAsAdmin()

strScriptPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strScriptPath )
strScriptFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -file " & strScriptFolder & "\Source\RemoveWindows10Apps-2.0.ps1"), 1 , True

...
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it.