# How can I keep powershell in repl mode with a loaded script

Tags: windows, powershell, stdin, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to start a powershell instance, that loads a script and remains open so I can still call methods loaded by that script manually.

I'm trying to dot source a script and pipe it to powershell like below, from a `cmd` instance/batchfile:

```
echo . .\script.ps1 | powershell
```

The result in this case is that powershell starts, loads my script, executes it and exits. I've tried running with `-noexit` argument, it has no effect.

I'm thinking of another option, to start a powershell process and pipe my dot source command to its stdin - but this probably won't allow me to interact with the process anymore because its stdin is opened by the host process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep the shell window open after running a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739322/how-to-keep-the-shell-window-open-after-running-a-powershell-script)

Comment: In short, rearrange your command to read `powershell -noexit .\script.ps1` and it should run your script while keeping the window open once it's done.

Comment: that solution does not work, powershell remains indeed open but I cannot access anything from `script.ps1`

Comment: Try dot sourcing it inside of the powershell command, like this `powershell -noexit ". .\script.ps1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run a script file so that window stays open and variables are accessible after the execution.

Try dot sourcing the script file like this:

```
powershell -noexit ". .\script.ps1"
```

Once the script is done, you can access any internal variable the script defined. Assuming the variables are at the script level scope.