# Powershell script reports execution-policy error when in a console window from File Explorer

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

My script runs fine in ISE however not in a PowerShell console window.

I have tried to replace any `"` with `'` (just in case it was an encoding error but I am not sure).

EDIT: The script works when copy and pasted into the console but not when opened with the console.

Here is the script, **ZAOCC.ps1**:

```
$path = '\\auisasvc2k801\safe\Information Technology\Support\Powershell\ZAOCC\Excel'
$path2 = '\\auisasvc2k801\safe\Information Technology\Support\Powershell\ZAOCC\PDF'
$xlFixedFormat = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType' -as [type]
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$objExcel.visible = $false
$date = Get-Date -Format 'dd.MM.yyyy'

foreach($workbook in $excelFiles)
{
    $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path2 -ChildPath ('Mine Control Record - ' + $date + '.pdf')
    $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($workbook.fullname, 3)
    $workbook.Saved = $true
    'Saving $filepath'
    $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)
    $objExcel.Workbooks.close()
}



$objExcel.Quit()
```

Here is the error message:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of RemoteSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more
information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:46
+ ...  -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & "\ ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739322/how-to-keep-the-shell-window-open-after-running-a-powershell-script

Comment: Edited post updated with error message.

Comment: @h0pper What is your Current Execution Policy ?

Comment: RemoteSigned @Roshan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you successfully change execution policy and enable execution of PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753917/how-do-you-successfully-change-execution-policy-and-enable-execution-of-powershe)

Comment: How do you call your script? Which parameters do you use? Obviously, you have a problem with the execution policy. Your error message does not come from your script you posted. "Line 1" looks different.

Answer (score 3):

The error message suggests that **you're running your script from File Explorer, using the shortcut menu's `Run with PowerShell` command** (which uses *Windows PowerShell*; note that PowerShell [Core] (v6+) no longer offers this command - see middle section).

Note that **doing so will automatically close the console window** that is opened to run the script **when the script exits**.

To avoid that, open a Windows PowerShell console window first, and then run your script from there - this will also make your problem go away.

(Another option is to modify the shortcut-menu command definition, as shown below.)

---

The reason for the error is that **your execution policy is set by either a machine-level or a user-level *Group Policy*, which takes precedence over the attempt to set the execution policy at the *process* level**.
**In fact, you *cannot* override an execution policy set via Group Policy from user code**, neither with a `Set-ExecutionPolicy` call nor via the `-ExecutionPolicy` CLI parameter.

**The attempt to set the execution at the process level - `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass` - is part of the command line that is used by the shortcut-menu command definition**, and it is it - not your script - that triggers the error.

**Therefore, the error message will appear on any system where the execution policy is defined via *Group Policy*, every time a script is directly invoked from File Explorer.**

Note that the error message is confusing in this case, claiming that the command "updated your execution policy successfully", when in reality it had *no effect*.

Also note that the error is a *statement*-terminating error<sup>[1]</sup>, which means that overall execution still continues and your script *is* invoked, despite the error - assuming that the Group Policy-set execution policy allows it.

In general, especially given that the console window automatically closes when the script terminates (for whatever reason), consider *not* using this direct-invocation feature.

In fact, **PowerShell [Core] (v6+) doesn't even offer this shortcut-menu command anymore and instead offers commands at the *directory* / *drive* level to open an *interactive* session *there*.**

---

If you still want to invoke your script via File Explorer and want to avoid the error message, **you can modify the shortcut-menu command definition in the registry** by simply removing the attempt to set the execution policy.

The definition is at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command` and modifying it requires *elevation* (running as admin); however, it is possible to create a *user-level* definition as well.

The following command redefines the shortcut-menu command definition so that `Set-ExecutionPolicy` is no longer called:

```bash
# NOTE: Requires elevation:
Set-ItemProperty registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\0\Command '(default)' @'
powershell.exe -NoLogo -File "%1"
'@
```

If you also want to keep the window open, add `-NoExit` as the first parameter.

---

<sup>[1] Generally speaking, the message shouldn't be an *error* at all; it should be a *warning*, as suggested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12032). However, in the interest of backward compatibility it was decided to keep the current behavior.</sup>