# Start-Process keep cmd window open?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that I am trying to run. It opens a CMD window, then closes it. I can briefly see and error. How can I get it to keep the window open so I can see the error? Here is my script I am running.

```
$ovfTool = "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool\ovftool.exe"
$user = "root"
$passwd = "MyPassWord"
$SrcESXi = "1.1.1.1"
$DstESXi = "1.1.1.2"
$DstDataStore = "disk-01"
$VM = "Ubuntu"

Start-Process $ovfTool -ArgumentList "--disableVerification --noSSLVerify --powerOn `
 -ds='$DstDataStore' vi://'$user':'$passwd'@'$SrcESXi'/'$VM' vi://'$user':'$passwd'@'$DstESXi'"
```

I have tried this as well. Adding the `-NoNewWindow` and `-Wait` with no luck

```
$ovfTool = "C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware OVF Tool\ovftool.exe"
$user = "root"
$passwd = "MyPassWord"
$SrcESXi = "1.1.1.1"
$DstESXi = "1.1.1.2"
$DstDataStore = "disk-01"
$VM = "Ubuntu"

Start-Process $ovfTool -ArgumentList "--disableVerification --noSSLVerify --powerOn `
 -ds='$DstDataStore' vi://'$user':'$passwd'@'$SrcESXi'/'$VM' vi://'$user':'$passwd'@'$DstESXi'" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: Already answered.  It is quicker to search before you ask... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244280/how-to-get-powershell-to-keep-a-command-window-open

Comment: You could potentially use the `-Wait` parameter and provide some way to require user input. Or you could use the `-RedirectStandardError error.txt`, which should contain any errors you normally see at the console.